# Is there a way to get multiple lists of labels/categories in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I've a situation where I want to be able to filter Trello multiple ways using the UI. For example, say I want to apply a Project C label and also a In Review label and then filter for just that using the sidebar.

Is the only way to do this just adding a lot of items to the main color labels and hoping it doesn't get confusing? Is there a plugin or a powerpack that will help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting multiple labels in the sidebar is the only way I am aware of.

1. Have you tried to click the label name, which toggles the label text, that should make it less confusing with a mix of labels?
2. If you have too many lists using a chrome extension [Trellists: Trello Lists Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trellists-trello-lists-ma/dgnlcodfeenegnifnpcabcclldoceeml?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to hide some of them with a quick click, may help the screen noise?